# What is the meaning of Build Agent in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs

What is the meaning of Build Agent in the Architectural of Team System Team Build?
I want to understand it to configuration the TFS for our company

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms181710.VS_BigBldArchOvrview(en-us,VS.90).png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A build agent is a machine that builds code. You define and request the build in Team Explorer and it it builds on another machine, the build agent.

You can use i for continuous integration or other builds.

Comment: Thanks Arve for your answer. When i create a build agent then i must input the working directory, what is the meaning of it?

Comment: That is where on the "build agent" PC where you build your code.